# Best way to process latex file with its own .sty (etc.) files all in the same dir

Tags: packages, templates, perl

I am thinking of making a Perl module to make it easy to format text data from within a Perl script: `Perl data structure + LaTeX template file -> LaTeX file -> run latex command on it -> produce pdf/ps output.`

My question is about when a LaTeX file depends on some `.sty`, `.cls` files which are private/specific to that file and are not installed system-wide, as opposed to, say, `graphicx`. (And I do not want them installed system-wide or even in my own user-wide dirs).

Let's say that the LaTeX file depends on `A.sty` and `B.cls` all living/provided/distributed together in this directory hierarchy the main feature being that they are always located in a `lib` subdir relative to the main LaTeX file:

```
/usr/share/templates/XYZ/main.tex.t
/usr/share/templates/XYZ/lib/A.sty
/usr/share/templates/XYZ/lib/B.cls
```

Ideally, I want to import `A.sty` and `B.cls` into `main.tex` using relative path notation. How to do that? Without installing these files system-wide or current-user-wide or in locations which LaTeX knows about?

A bit more information on what this "template" system is:

The file `main.tex.t` is a template which means it contains LaTeX but can also contain things like `The title is "<: title :>"`, `\textit{<: author :>}`, `\usepackage{<: package :>}`, etc. These template vars will be replaced by Perl in order to produce the `main.tex` which then is processed (for example from within Perl with module `LaTeX::Driver`). Which means I can control environment variables too.

So, it is possible to include via template var even the absolute location of the `.sty` files in the final LaTeX source file.

I use xelatex because of multilingual support, but perhaps I can also use pdflatex with your suggestions? But I am not yet into LuaTeX.

Comment: if you mean you are getting perl to run latex just get it to locally set the environment `TEXINPUTS=.//:` then tex will recursively search subdirectories before the standard path